# Changing list layouts back to original layout

Tags: trello

I discovered that I could change the layout from horizontal to vertical by moving the shape of my browser around. That was cool. But now I want the layout of my lists to go back to horizontal and I have not discovered a way to do this. When I make my browser smaller, they become vertical, when I make my browser bigger, they stay vertical and do not return to the original horizontal layout. How do I change them back to the original way they were?

Answer (score 5):

The Trello layout should automatically adapt when you change the size of the window.

If you find that it is stuck (for some reason), try refreshing the page.

(Trello doesn't actually store the vertical list vs side-by-side orientation; the only reason I could think that it'd get stuck is if there were a Javascript error that prevented the layout from updating.  You can check your browsers error console by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd>)

Comment: I'm on a work computer, so I don't have all the options I would normally have. When I press F12 nothing happens, and I have to work with the version of firefox I've been given. I think they just came out with a new one? Could that fix it? It's just not going back to horizontal when I broaden the browser window or press the expand button in the corner.